# Iperf and Mininet (Floodlight)

Tags: python, openflow, mininet

I am working on a load balance project using Mininet and Floodlight. The topology is fat tree:

4 Core Switches,
8 Aggregation Switches,
Edge Switches, and
16 Hosts

I need to create a text file (#1) that has tens of lines using (iperf UDP)to send packet from source to destination within time limit and packet size. Something like this:

10.0.0.2,10.3.1.3,7m,3Mbps,
10.0.0.2,10.3.1.2,9m,9Mbps, etc.

The idea is to have a python code in a text file (#2) and run it within the Mininet terminal and it will read the text file (1) and start sending packets. I am not sure how to do this! I am used to open two hosts' terminal and use iperf to make one host as a client and the other as a server. So, in my case how can I do that?

The problem is when we create a topology and I am inside (mininet>) I could not execute any python code since I am limited to certain commands to run. Therefore, I tried to execute some Python code in the Mininet terminal (mininet@mininet-vm:-$) and Icould not get it working knowing that I was able to execute the python code inside this terminal.

I also tried to run iperf script within the same code of the topology (fat tree), but I for some reason did not get it working either!

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

You could open an xterm host and use iperf to send your file, like this:
$ xterm h1 
$ iperf -c  -F

Here is a nice reference for iperf: https://iperf.fr/.

If you would like to use Scapy, try this:

```
data = "University of Network blah blah"
a = IP(dst="129.132.2.21")/TCP()/data
send(a)
```